# never started elasticsearch node but got ERROR: Skipping security auto configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I got token from already running master node with following command

```
bin\elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node
```

I ran other node that I've never strated

```
bin\elasticsearch --enrollment-token <enrollment-token>
```

but I got this error message

```
ERROR: Skipping security auto configuration because it appears that security is already configured.
```

I've never ran this node but It keep saying I did and `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes` doesn’t help

I  set inbound rule in AWS like:

```
IPv4    HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0   

IPv4    SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   

IPv4    HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   

IPv4        custom TCP  TCP 9200 - 9399 0.0.0.0/0   

IPv6    custom  TCP TCP 9200 - 9399 ::/0
```

and I set master node on my instatce following these steps:

```
#1
sudo yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64

#2
sudo rpm --import https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch

#3 
sudo nano /etc/yum.repos.d/elasticsearch.repo

#4 save these lines on elasticsearch.repon
[elasticsearch]
name=Elasticsearch repository for 8.x packages
baseurl=https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/yum
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
enabled=0
autorefresh=1
type=rpm-md

#5
sudo yum install --enablerepo=elasticsearch elasticsearch

#6
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/**elasticsearch**
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch
sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch

#7
sudo su elasticsearch -s /bin/bash 

#8
cd /etc/elasticsearch

#9 change elasticsearch config settings
cluster.name: dev-cluster
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: _site_
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["ip-100-10-10-10.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["ip-100-10-10-10.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal"]

xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12

http.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: 0.0.0.0

#10 start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch

#11 get password of elastic accound 
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password --username user1 -i
```

then I stopped master node, started again with command ./bin/elasticsearch -d and I got this log

```
[2022-10-27T17:32:11,581][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] version[8.4.3], pid[31711], build[rpm/42f05b9372a9a4a470db3b52817899b99a76ee73/2022-10-04T07:17:24.662462378Z], OS[Linux/5.10.144-127.601.amzn2.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/18.0.2.1/18.0.2.1+1-1]

[2022-10-27T17:32:11,586][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]

[2022-10-27T17:32:11,587][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-14995458373941900172, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Xms1959m, -Xmx1959m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1027604480, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=rpm, --module-path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]

[2022-10-27T17:32:13,376][INFO ][c.a.c.i.j.JacksonVersion ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.13.2, jackson-core=2.13.2, jackson-databind=2.13.2.2, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.13.2, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.13.2, azure-core=1.27.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,680][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,681][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [analysis-common]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,681][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [constant-keyword]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,682][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [data-streams]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,682][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [frozen-indices]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,682][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [ingest-attachment]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,683][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [ingest-common]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,683][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [ingest-geoip]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,683][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,684][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [kibana]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,684][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [lang-expression]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,684][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [lang-mustache]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,685][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [lang-painless]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,685][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [legacy-geo]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,685][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [mapper-extras]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,686][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [mapper-version]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,686][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [old-lucene-versions]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,686][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [parent-join]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,686][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [percolator]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,687][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [rank-eval]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,687][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [reindex]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,687][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [repositories-metering-api]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,688][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [repository-azure]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,688][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [repository-encrypted]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,688][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [repository-gcs]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,688][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [repository-s3]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,689][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [repository-url]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,689][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [runtime-fields-common]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,689][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [search-business-rules]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,690][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [searchable-snapshots]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,690][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [snapshot-based-recoveries]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,690][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [snapshot-repo-test-kit]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,690][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [spatial]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,691][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [systemd]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,691][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [transform]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,691][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [transport-netty4]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,692][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [unsigned-long]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,692][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [vector-tile]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,692][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [wildcard]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,692][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-aggregate-metric]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,693][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,693][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-async]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,693][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-async-search]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,693][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-autoscaling]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,694][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,694][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-core]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,694][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,694][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,695][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-eql]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,695][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-fleet]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,695][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-graph]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,695][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-identity-provider]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,696][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,696][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,696][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-ml]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,696][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,697][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-ql]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,697][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,697][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-security]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,697][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-shutdown]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,698][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-sql]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,698][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-stack]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,698][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-text-structure]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,698][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,699][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]

[2022-10-27T17:32:14,699][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] no plugins loaded

[2022-10-27T17:32:17,885][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [12gb], net total_space [14.9gb], types [xfs]

[2022-10-27T17:32:17,885][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]

[2022-10-27T17:32:17,935][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] node name [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal], node ID [zl8ftWOcT_OJImkuzARXzw], cluster name [kp-dev-cluster], roles [transform, data_content, data_warm, master, remote_cluster_client, data, data_cold, ingest, data_frozen, ml, data_hot]

[2022-10-27T17:32:21,155][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security         ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] Security is enabled

[2022-10-27T17:32:21,504][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] parsed [0] roles from file [/etc/elasticsearch/roles.yml]

[2022-10-27T17:32:21,998][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] [controller/31749] [Main.cc@123] controller (64 bit): Version 8.4.3 (Build 9c00cf51c9fea9) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV

[2022-10-27T17:32:22,558][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]

[2022-10-27T17:32:22,588][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]

[2022-10-27T17:32:22,630][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,113][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] initialized

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,114][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] starting ...

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,127][INFO ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] persistent cache index loaded

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,128][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] deprecation component started

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,230][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] publish_address {172.31.44.89:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,524][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,545][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] this node is locked into cluster UUID [1V1YFJcKRh6FUZvuKcSzWQ] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,657][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{zl8ftWOcT_OJImkuzARXzw}{3Ak1MYQsROiwqqdy5sp47w}{ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{172.31.44.89}{172.31.44.89:9300}{cdfhilmrstw} completing election], term: 3, version: 38, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{zl8ftWOcT_OJImkuzARXzw}{3Ak1MYQsROiwqqdy5sp47w}{ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{172.31.44.89}{172.31.44.89:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,703][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] master node changed {previous [], current [{ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{zl8ftWOcT_OJImkuzARXzw}{3Ak1MYQsROiwqqdy5sp47w}{ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{172.31.44.89}{172.31.44.89:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}, term: 3, version: 38, reason: Publication{term=3, version=38}

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,781][INFO ][o.e.r.s.FileSettingsService] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] starting file settings watcher ...

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,798][INFO ][o.e.r.s.FileSettingsService] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] file settings service up and running [tid=42]

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,805][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] publish_address {172.31.44.89:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}

[2022-10-27T17:32:24,806][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal] started {ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{zl8ftWOcT_OJImkuzARXzw}{3Ak1MYQsROiwqqdy5sp47w}{ip-172-31-44-89.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal}{172.31.44.89}{172.31.44.89:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{ml.max_jvm_size=2055208960, ml.allocated_processors=2, xpack.installed=true, ml.machine_memory=4110344192}
```

and this is my second node’s config

```
cluster.name: dev-cluster
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: _site_
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["ip-100-10-10-10.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["ip-100-10-10-10.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal"]

xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12

http.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: 0.0.0.0
```

I installed second node following exactly same step I used when installing master node except running node and setting password

what's wrong with this